# Blazor Web Assembly No line error on Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a Blazor WebAssembly application .Net 6 and have encountered a peculiar behavior regarding the display of exception details. While in my local development environment, I can see complete details of exceptions, including file path and line number, this is not the case when the application is published on Azure Static Web Apps.

**Local Environment:**

[image: Local environment exception]

**Azure Static Web App Environment:**

[image: Azure Static Web App Environment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, you don't get line numbers in optimised code, even in ASP.Net Razor, MVC or Web API.

That is the difference, to publish to Azure you are most likely using the default **Release** build configuration. You can get the same experience locally by switching the build configuration to **Release**.

Welcome to .Net!

Comment: It is possible to change the deployment configuration to _Debug_ and include PDP files and not optimise the code... But I really do not want to encourage that.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your response, but I have a doubt about how you track errors that occur in production if you don't know the line where they occur? This forces applications to be published in debug. I use Application Insights in my Blazor WebAssembly application and the error line does not appear either, even when I use ILogger.

Comment: Something curious happened, I published in Debug but I still can't see the error line :(

Comment: That is a very naive view, that you need line numbers to resolve issues that occur in production. It is a fundamental OWASP security consideration that you do not expose information like line numbers or filenames in error messages from production code. The stack trace you see now is more secure by default, but still too obvious to an attacker so you would want to ensure only your logging insights contains this information. Knowing the type of error and the method that it occurs in is usually more than enough to identify and resolve bugs without line numbers.

Comment: Did you actually change the publish configuration, or did you just change the local configuration? Also make sure that you untick "optomise" and you will also need to include the ".pdb" files in the output. These options are generally disabled by default in publish profiles. Either way, the standard way to identify line number would be to replicate the issue in a local debug environment, in Blazor you can easily set a debugging break point on the method identified as having the issue and step through the logic.

Comment: I forgot of course that if you are publishing pre-compiled or self contained, then you won't get line numbers at all in the deployed environment. It's not that the target is Azure, it is the type of deployment model you have selected. I'll put a remark about this in my answer.